# C++11: Custom range-based loop without copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

I would like to have a custom range-based loop but without a copy constructor. It seems there is a copy at some point but I do not understand why.

Here is the sample I would like to run: http://cpp.sh/63pa6

```
class Range
{
public:
    Range( int begin, int end )
        : iter_( begin ),
          last_( end )
    {
    }
    Range(Range&&) = default;
    Range& operator=(Range&&) = default;

    Range(const Range&) = delete;

    bool operator!=( const Range & /*unused*/ ) const
    {
        return iter_ != last_;
    }

    void operator++()
    {
        ++iter_;
    }

    const Range &begin() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    const Range &end() const
    {
        return *this;
    }

    int operator*() const
    {
        return iter_;
    }
private:
    int iter_;
    int last_;
};
```

This code does not compile:

```
int main()
{
    for( auto i : Range( 2, 8 ) )
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compilation error: `error: use of deleted function 'Range::Range(const Range&)'`

Comment: You need to add a [mcve] please.

Comment: I believe the end iterator always gets copied in a range-based for loop. Your end iterator should be a sentinel object instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range based for loop [produces the following code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
{
  auto && __range = range_expression ; 
  for (auto __begin = begin_expr, __end = end_expr; 
    __begin != __end; ++__begin) { 
    range_declaration = *__begin; 
    loop_statement 
  } 
}
```

As you can see, this creates two copies, `__begin` and `__end`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simpler when you define iterator wrapper:

```
struct range : std::pair<int,int> {
    struct int_iter {
        int_iter( int i ) : i(i) {}
        int operator*() { return i; }
        int &operator++() { return ++i; }
        bool operator!=( int_iter end ) const { return i != end.i; }
    private:    
        int i;
    };
    using std::pair<int,int>::pair;
    int_iter begin() const { return int_iter( first ); }
    int_iter end() const { return int_iter(second); }
};
```

[live example](https://ideone.com/hiSWmh)